# Reading, interpreting and exporting SNMP messages

Tags: snmp

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to use SNMP in my networks. It's for industrial applications, networks with 200-800 IPs, but many quirks and security layers.

What I'd like to do is catch any traps, and periodically read parameters, over SNMP for all my network equipment. It will be sent to an external system for storage and viewing.

I understand now that even though my equipment uses the SNMP standards, the same OIDs can sometimes mean different things, and I then have to get all the MIB files from the vendors.
I find many parsers that can give me information from within the MIBs, but what I need is a whole system for importing MIBs, adding them to some kind of library, and for me to know which devices are currently supported by my library. Then, when I receive a message, I need the system to figure out what equipment has sent that, look up the correct info from the MIB and construct an alarm message based on that.

1. Is there any solution today that can take a list of IPs and send SNMP-get messages to all of those?
2. Do I need any setup just to receive SNMP traps, or will they just be
   attempted delivered at the specified IP address, and I need only to
   listen at the correct port?
3. Is there any way to parse all those MIBs and turn them into a manageable library?
4. How do I associate the devices with the info from the MIBs, so I interpret the information correctly?

I want to make a general solution for this, so I can expand it to more devices and vendors easily later. Below is a sketch of how a typical network would look like, but of course with a lot more components in real life. Hope someone has some good input.

[image: SNMP concept]

Comment: A few typical mistakes. 1) TRAP messages are only sent by SNMP agents to destinations if properly configured, so "catch any traps" without configuration in advance is impossible. 2) MIB document parsing is so common if you search for MIB parsers/compilers. 3) The information from MIB documents are only useful when you capture TRAP messages and see into their data. Rather vague to discuss further without a concrete example.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. 1) You're right, I missed that. Okay, so I configure the destination on all the equipment, does that mean I can listen on my manager without knowing any specifics of where the information would come from?
2) Yes, there are many parsers, and I'm sure that parsing it is very solvable, but there are projects with various age, popularity and support. So I would love to hear first hand what people have used
3) managing a library of many MIB files and associating MIB files with equipment is what I'm concerned about. I'm updating my first post to clarify the system.

Comment: The answer to 1) is yes, many, from free to expensive. You need to do your due diligence. For a smattering of NMS apps, see http://doc.gambitcom.com/update/doc/samplenet2019.shtml

Comment: The answer to 2) is: once your TRAP destination is  setup, all you need is a collector at that IP. But, not worth much as explained in previous comment. REAL NMS apps take the traps as hints to investigate and do root-cause analysis. The TRAP is part of your solution, as is SNMP, ICMP, and other collection methods.

Comment: To continue the discussion 1) Your manager should get all TRAP messages then, and the common SNMP packet format ensures that all objects can be decoded. However, interpreting the OIDs require domain knowledge from the MIB documents. 2) As I am one of the parser vendors, I cannot give an unbiased advice for this one. You will have to do your own evaluation. 3) Managing MIB documents is something you have to handle. Once you choose a parser, its vendor will guide you further.

Comment: I've read through most of your code from SharpSnmpLib, and the amount of classes are a little daunting, but it really has the potential to do what I want it to do in the end run. As you can guess, I'm at a proof-of-concept stage, but making a no-frills, powerful way of collecting SNMP data, that can be deployed in new networks with a minimal (but realistic) amount of work is my end-goal. Common vendors are Cisco, Moxa, Aruba, in addition to Mototrbo and some licenced band radio link systems. Looks like the 'library' or 'association' part is the unknown factor in this, at the moment.